# Rails commands only work on one terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I installed Ruby and then RVM, and then configured Rails.

It all works when I call it from the original terminal.  But when I try to call various commands from new terminals, the system just gives an error message such as this one:

```
$rails server
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Why does that happen?  Is there some global variable which needs to be set?  I am using Ubuntu by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example of how/where gems are installed:

```
rvm use 1.8.7
ruby -v           # 1.8.7 returned
rvm gemdir        # some directory returned 
gem install rails # (installed to the directory returned by `rvm gemdir` in 1.8.7)
rails -v          # some version returned 

rvm use 1.9.2
ruby -v           # 1.9.2 returned
rvm gemdir        # some directory returned 
rails -v          # Error if not installed, else version is shown
gem install rails # (installed to the directory returned by `rvm gemdir` in 1.9.2)
rails -v          # some version returned
```

Now, the Rails gem is now installed in 2 directories (1 for each of the Ruby versions)

Now in order to set a default version of Ruby (instead of typing `rvm use` every time you open a terminal), you can run:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

See the [documentation](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/) for more information about default.

Some other commands:

- Default ruby `rvm list default`
- All Rubies: `rvm list`

Also note **[do not use `sudo` with RVM!](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/)**

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: I got this message: WARN: ruby ruby-1.8.7-p334 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p334' - but it does not make sense since I definitely have RVM installed and I did the command from the terminal in which it is working.  Any ideas? :)

Comment: Is `ruby -v` working? Is Rails gem installed in the directory shown by `rvm gemdir`? Maybe you installed it in a different version of Ruby (and thus in a different directory). Use `gem which rails` in the terminal where you installed it to see which directory it got installed to.

Comment: $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux] - so should I just use the command you suggested with the more current version number?

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: I gave 1.8.7 only as an example (dont install it if you dont want to, but RVM makes it so easy to have multiple versions of rubies and gems for each of them)

Answer (score 0):

It's also important to note that gnome terminal needs to have access to the login shell. This can be configured on Ubuntu 12.04 by right-clicking on your terminal pane, clicking **Profiles > Profile Preferences** selecting the **Title and Command** pane and toggling the option `Run command as login shell`.

Source: [RVM + Gnome Terminal](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

After setting rvm default,

```
    bash --login
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem configuring the terminal on ubuntu to  'Run command as login shell'

follow this simple tutorial

https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.